# Read Xref manual in Emacs

Tags: info, xref

I want to read [Xref (Find Identifiers References)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Xref.html) in Emacs.

When running `info` <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and then `Info-menu` <kbd>m</kbd>, I can not find any Xref topic.
I have `helm` enabled, so it completes topics on info.
For example, it completes `EDE` which appears in [Maintaining Large Programs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Maintaining.html), Xref parent page.

How can I invoke Xref help on Emacs info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the Emacs manual: do `C-h i m emacs RET i xref RET` and you should get there. The `i xref RET` part looks for `xref` in the index of the Emacs manual.

Comment: Great, thank you!